# Static IP Configuration_Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, server

I have a problem setting static IP on my Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS.

My computer has 2 interfaces `p2p1` and `p1p1`. The `p2p1` node - primary node - should be visible form the outer world.

I use the following code to configure IP.

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto p2p1
    iface p2p1 inet static
    address 192.168.2.202
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.2.0
    broadcast 192.168.2.255
    gateway 192.168.2.1
    dns-nameservers 192.168.2.1

auto p1p1
    address 192.168.2.203
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.2.0
    broadcast 192.168.2.255
    gateway 192.168.2.1
    dns-nameservers 192.168.2.1
```

However, after the network configuration is not working have no internet and `ping www.google.com` is not working.

Earlier I had used the Ubuntu 12.04 and it has `eth0` and `eth1` and I have not more experience about the ubuntu.

I have two questions.

1. `eth0` in ubuntu 12.04 and `p2p1` in ubuntu 14.04 are same.
2. how to configure the two NIC at Ubuntu 14.04 for use the

   - `p2p1` for world wide web services
   - `p1p1` for FTP and VPN connection.

Comment: Have you set the default route? What's the output of `route -n`? Are your `dns-nameservers` values correct? They are both an octet short: `192.168.2`?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's good to have to gateways,

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto p2p1
    iface p2p1 inet static
    address 192.168.2.202
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.2.0
    broadcast 192.168.2.255
    #gateway 192.168.2.1
    #dns-nameservers 192.168.2.

auto p1p1
    address 192.168.2.203
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.2.0
    broadcast 192.168.2.255
    gateway 192.168.2.1
    #dns-nameservers 192.168.2
```

and instead of putting dns-nameservers severs in the network interface, try changing `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base` like the following:

```
# Google IPv4 nameservers
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

You also need to run `resolvconf -u` for the changes to be reflected.

Comment: +1. You also need to run `resolvconf -u` for the changes to be reflected. Sorry, I forgot to mention that.

Comment: @muru thanks  , you can always be free to edit my answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is different flags being set for dnsmasq for static IPs vs dynamic IP addresses.

For static IP address, dnsmasq sets --proxy-dnssec by default. Most ISPs do not provide dnssec capable DNS servers and therefore dnsmaq hangs.

If you set the IP addresses for the DNS servers to a publicly offered DNS server (google is a good one: 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4) everything will work. You do not need to override resolve in any other way.