# Waiting for network configuration (on boot-up)

Tags: boot, networking

I've noticed lately on my new 14.04 Server that I get the following on boot-up:

```
Waiting for network configuration
```

followed by:

```
Waiting up to 60 more seconds for network configuration
```

and eventually followed by:

```
Booting system without full network configuration
```

I've read some places that this has to do with the /etc/network/interfaces configuration, and I don't necessarily see anything wrong with how mine is configured, but here it is:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).


# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback


# The primary network interface
auto p2p1
iface p2p1 inet static
    address 192.168.79.249
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.79.1
    dns-nameservers 192.168.79.1 8.8.8.8


auto p3p1
iface p3p1 inet static
    address 192.168.79.252
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.79.1
    dns-nameservers 192.168.79.1 8.8.8.8
```

I do have two NIC's in the system just in case anyone is wondering.

Any help is greatly appreciated if this is something that I need to be concerned about. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Static IP Configuration\_Ubuntu 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/526218/static-ip-configuration-ubuntu-14-04)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after upgrading kernel.

When I executed

```
ifup eth0
```

I got

```
device not found
```

So the problem was not configuration.

My solution: Boot with different kernel.

You can check if you have other kernels in your pc executing:

```
ls /usr/src/
```

And you will have entries like this one:

```
linux-headers-3.13.0-64/
```

To boot with different kernel, when booting press SHIFT key and select "advanced ubuntu options" and try selecting different kernels until you find the one that works. After that, remove other kernels.